# Angular 2 - IE11 The value of the property 'webpackJsonp' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: angular, webpack, internet-explorer-11

I am new to Angular 2. I installed Angular-CLI (followed https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and created a sample project.

Now, I built the app using   "ng build --prod" and had the "dist" folder hosted in IIS.
When I browse to the site using "localhost/index.html" in IE11, everything works. 
The moment i browse to the same site using the server address "ServerName/index.html"   I am getting:

***IE11 The value of the property 'webpackJsonp' is null or undefined, not a Function object***

However, doing the same in GoogleChrome and Firefox works just fine!

Your help/tips is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured it out. I had IE11 in Compatibility mode. I removed it and everything works now.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. I had IE11 in Compatibility mode. I removed it and everything works now. –

Comment: Oh my God... this one *again* ?!  We had this with IE8 on our in-house apps.  IE8 in Compatibility Mode would prevent any HTML5 code from working, so our apps didn't work.  Why is this setting still there ?!  Aaaagghhh !!!    Thanks for the tip...